# how to naturally rotate a ball according to its velocity on a surface, a wall

Tags: sprites, cocos2d-x, rotate

I develop a game on cocos2d-x cpp. There is a ball sprite in my game. I move the ball on a surface(wall) via touch events but it can't naturally rotate according to its velocity.

if i use ballSprite->runAction(..) in update(float dt) method then it doesn't rotate.

i use following code:

```
void GameLayer::updateBall(float dt)
{
  float deltaRotateX = 360.0f * _ballVelocityX;
  _ballSprite->setRotation(90.0f- CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(deltaRotateX));
}
```

But the ball doesn't naturally rotate. it discretely rotate.
it can't naturally rotate according to its velocity.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add a video of what's going on? and what you're expecting to have?

Comment: Be aware that the ball should make one full rotation for every 2Pi* ball radius that it travels along the wall.

Answer (score 3):

Edit:

Here is some math

```
Circ = radius * 2 * 3.14

dx = ball_speed * dt
```

to get  deltaAngle  `a` lets solve  `a/dx=(2*3.14)/circ`

```
a = (2*3.14*dx)/circ
```

sobstituting `circ = radius * 2 * 3.14`

we get

`a = dx/radius`

so delta angle belongs to speed , dt and radius

putting this stuff into love2d we get

```
function ent:update(dt) 
    local dx = ent.speed*dt
    local alpha = dx / (ent.radius )
    self.x = self.x + dx    --update position
    ent.rot=ent.rot +  alpha --update rotation
end
```

follows a test example:

[image]

Finaly , adding acceleration :

```
function ent:update(dt) 
    ent.speed = ent.speed + ent.accel *dt
    local dx = ent.speed*dt
    local alpha = dx / (ent.radius )
    self.x = self.x + dx    --update position
    ent.rot=ent.rot +  alpha --update rotation
end
```

we get

[image]

Comment: i have tried your suggestion with angle = dx / radius and it didn't correctly run. But it correctly runs with angle = dx / 2 * 3.14 * radius (angle = distance / circumference). Thanks for your and Peethor's suggestions.